# How to use correlated input data to create a ML model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, correlation, independence

I would like to create a machine learning model with R using, for example, the simple linear regression.

For independent observations, I use the command
`model <- lm(Y~., data=my_data)`

But I have the following dataset, where the observations are correlated:

[image]

To be specific, I have different types of steel (IDs) and 2 substances (X1 and X2) that have a corrosive effect (Y) on them.
The substances are considered in 2 different quantities (in ascending order) and all the 8 rows consider their different combination.
For example:
Row1 -> taking only subtance1 in quantity 1cl, gives the effect of 1% of corrosion for the steel of type1.
Row 8 -> the combination of subst.1 in quantity 2cl and subst.2 in quantity 2cl gives the effect of 9% of corrosion for the steel of type1.

Then, I have other types of steel (steel2, steel3, etc.) treated with the same subtances (subst.1 and subst.2) in different quantities (1.5cl and 3.2cl for steel2, 2.3cl and 3.8cl for steel3, etc.) in all the 8 combinations.

What I would like to do with a machine learning model (if it is possible) is to predict the value of the effect of the 2 substances for a new kind of steel, taking as input the 2 subtances and their effects when they are taken singularly, in order to have the prediction of the effects when the substances are taken combined.

Do you think it is possible and, in this case, could you give me any suggestions about the method I have to use?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not fully sure what you mean with "the observations (rows) from 1 to 8 are correlated". Do you mean that for each ID, the vectors X1 and X2 are correlated? Or that the values of Y within each ID are correlated (so IDs with higher values of Y in one row tend to also have higher values of Y in the other rows)? Or that the unique values occuring in X1 and X2 are correlated (so IDs with a higher maximum value in X1/X2 tend to have also a higher medium value in X1/X2)?
Andy why do you think this correlation is a problem?

Comment: Thank you for your questions (and your time). I think my case falls within your third sentence (the unique values occuring in X1 and X2 are correlated, so IDs with a higher maximum value in X1/X2 tend to have also a higher medium value in X1/X2). Effectively I was still not clear in my original question, sorry. I have updated it again with a sample case. I hope it is better now and I'd be grateful if you can suggest me if machine learning is the right way to approach this problem. The more I deepen it, the more I have doubts...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a [hierarchical regression model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model) where you basically estimate separate regression weights for each of your "blocks" of observations. You usually assume that across blocks, the distribution of a regression weight follows a normal distribution, e.g. every block *j* has an intercept $b_{0j}$ with $b_{0j} \sim N(\tilde b_0, s_{b_0})$.

In R, you can implement this relatively easily using the `lme4` package.

```
library(lme4)
model <- lmer(Y ~ 1+X1*X2 + (1+X1*X2|id), data=my_data)
```

Here, the `(1+X1*X2|id)` part specifies the regression weights that you want separately for each block (identified by `id` in your data frame). The output of the model will give you the mean and the standard deviation of the weight distribution.

Comment: Assuming the data are not serial (longitudinal) then there may be no avoiding a hierarchical model, or using GEE with an after-the-fact cluster covariance adjustment.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have realized I was unclear in my question, so I have updated it. I hope it is better now. I think it is not a problem solvable with a hierarchical model...Do you see other options?